# Show alertbox when a user select a non accepted file in danialfarid/ng-file-upload plugin

Tags: angularjs, angular-file-upload

- I am using [danialfarid/ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) plugin ,I set the ngf-select directive to .doc,.pdf extension. Its working fine.

  - Problem is if a user select .png or jpg file, I want to show an alert box to user that this file type are not accepted.
    Thanks for in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this (haven't tested the code, but you can get the idea):

HTML

```
<button type="button" ngf-select="set($file)" ngf-pattern="'.doc,.pdf'">Select file...</button>
```

JS (in your controller)

```
$scope.set = function(file) {
    if(file 
        && file.$error
        && (file.$errorParam.indexOf('.png') > -1
            || file.$errorParam.indexOf('.jpg') > -1)
    ){
        alert('file type is not allowed ):');
    }
}
```

Or you can use the `input` element with `accept`, which in most browsers won't even let the user select other file types:

```
<input type="file" ngf-select accept=".doc,.pdf"></input>
```

Comment: Thank so much for your response, its not working , when I select file other than mention in ngf-accept, it neither  invoke $upload method , nor show any flag that file you select is not accepted.

Comment: I want that if I set ngf-accept directive and if I select non mention file type , then we show an alert to user that file type are not accepted